# Tomcat 7 + Jersey + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

I followed this guide http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html but i'm stopped at the point 5.4 because when i start my application i'have this error:

```
mag 26, 2014 7:11:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
mag 26, 2014 7:11:09 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Avvertenza: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:de.vogella.jersey.first' did not find a matching property.
mag 26, 2014 7:11:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 26, 2014 7:11:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 26, 2014 7:11:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 1421 ms
mag 26, 2014 7:11:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
mag 26, 2014 7:11:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
mag 26, 2014 7:11:11 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Informazioni: validateJarFile(C:\Users\p3pp0n5\Desktop\Programmazione\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\de.vogella.jersey.first\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
mag 26, 2014 7:11:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Informazioni: Marking servlet Jersey REST Service as unavailable
mag 26, 2014 7:11:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
Grave: Servlet /de.vogella.jersey.first threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

mag 26, 2014 7:11:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mag 26, 2014 7:11:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mag 26, 2014 7:11:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 3318 ms
```

My web.xml file and my java code is the same that you can see in the guide.
Sorry for my english... Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you made sure that you have filled all the requisites in the manual?  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html  It looks like it cannot find some native DLL

Comment: Yes, i've tomcat7 and if i start it alone (execute file startup.bat) it work... but not with eclipse... I followed the tutorial several times and always I've this problem... i do not what can i do... The only thing I can do is uninstall eclipse and do it all again...

Comment: Are you sure you have all the jars?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all the jars?

```
asm-5.0.jar
asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
hk2-api-2.3.0.jar
hk2-locator-2.3.0.jar
hk2-utils-2.3.0.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.10.jar
jersey-apache-connector-2.12.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-grizzly2-http-2.1.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-guava-2.8.jar
jersey-server.jar
org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
swt_win32_x86.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```